# How to get embbed XML from XML

Tags: android, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a little problem, during sending request to serwer I'm getting xml with embedded xml in it. Application works on Android 2.1 so I can not just use `getTextContent()` to get value, so I'm using `Node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();` and for standard node with text it works fine but for node with embedded xml in it, it isn't. Does someone have any advice or had the same problem? How to solve it.

BTW: When I checked type of node all of the are 1 so it means ELEMENT_NODE.

Comment: Well, I found solution, before getting value use Node.noramlize();

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  One thing to note is that you need to normalize the level above the level that your XML text is on in order to flatten it into one child node.  (BTW, you should answer your own question so it can be marked answered)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you receiving from server? Something like;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<embedded-xml>
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <data/>
</embedded-xml>
```

Or;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<embedded-xml>
  <data/>
</embedded-xml>
```

In latter case you can simply retrieve data -node (not value), there's no need to parse it separately, while first case isn't exactly valid afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed an arbitrary XML document in an XML document because XML documents can include sequences which are illegal with CDATA sections that are required to embed XML in the first place.

If the task is being able to embed, then extract, an arbitrary XML document, you have to encode the XML document, then embed it in a CDATA section.  The reason is that the closing tag for CDATA is "]]>" and if the (arbitrary) embedded document contains a CDATA section, the "]]>" tag for that documents CDATA section will close the CDATA section in the parent.

In my experience, the best approach to embedding XML inside of XML is to compress (because Base64 encoding is going to blow it up ...) then Base64 encode.  The reason I've taken this approach is because it is fool-proof and the two transforms (some kind of compressor and base64 en/de-coding) are widely available.